# reverse numerical sort for list in python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting, reverse

I'm trying to create python implementations from an algorithms book I'm going through. Though I'm sure that python probably has these functions built in, I thought it would be a good exercise to learn the language a bit.

The algorithm given was to create an insertion sorting loop for a numerical array. This I was able to get working just fine. I then tried to modify it to perform a reverse sort (largest number to lowest number). The output is almost there but I'm not sure where it goes wrong.

First, the sort for increasing numbers:

```
sort_this = [31,41,59,26,41,58]
print sort_this

for j in range(1,len(sort_this)):
    key = sort_this[j]
    i = j - 1
    while i >= 0 and sort_this[i] > key:
        sort_this[i + 1] = sort_this[i]
        i -= 1
    sort_this[i + 1] = key
    print sort_this
```

Now, the reverse sort which does not work:

```
sort_this = [5,2,4,6,1,3]
print sort_this

for j in range(len(sort_this)-2, 0, -1):
    key = sort_this[j]
    i = j + 1
    while i < len(sort_this) and sort_this[i] > key:
        sort_this[i - 1] = sort_this[i]
        i += 1
        print sort_this
    sort_this[i - 1] = key
    print sort_this
```

The output for the above is:

```
[5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3] 
[5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 3] 
[5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1] 
[5, 2, 4, 6, 3, 1] 
[5, 2, 6, 6, 3, 1] 
[5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1] 
[5, 6, 6, 4, 3, 1] 
[5, 6, 4, 4, 3, 1] 
[5, 6, 4, 3, 3, 1] 
[5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

The final array is almost sorted except for the first 2 numbers. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Why not just use `sort_this[i] < key`? No need to loop in the other direction here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`range` does not include the end value.  When you do `range(len(sort_this)-2, 0, -1)`, your iteration goes from `len(sort_this)-2` to 1, so you never hit the first element (at index 0).  Change your range to `range(len(sort_this)-2, -1, -1)`